# Will installing a deadbolt on a 1920s bathroom door decrease the resale value

Tags: doors, deadbolt, antique

If this is the wrong place to ask, I apologize and please direct me to the right place. Common sense arguments are welcome.

My house has 1920s era doors with crystal door knobs
example here: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/ac/8b/c4/ac8bc45b7ec7415478fb315ff326696a--crystal-knobs-glass-door-knobs.jpg

The door in my home is in far worse shape than the picture above. The knob and key are actually one piece built into the door frame. The key mechanism in the door is beyond repair and it cannot be replaced, this door does not lock.

I have installed a deadbolt similar to this:
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41vaXTd1sBL._SY300_QL70_.jpg

It blends in nicely with the color of the door.

Will this decrease the value of the home? Are 1920s era doors a selling point for home buyers?

Personally, I think a bathroom door that locks would be more important to a home buyer than the antique appearance of the door (especially considering the classic door has a broken key mechanism that is beyond repair).

If you have hard stats from surveys of home-buyers, that would be great, but I'm also open to general comments. Thanks.

Comment: VTC as resale value is off-topic here

Comment: Crystal knobs like that are available at places like Home Depot & Lowes.  The skeleton key lock is something you would probably need to check for at a renovator supply store.  But anything that requires a key is dangerous.  re: deadbolt with key hidden in a closet -- emergency personnel and non-family members won't know about it.  In an emergency, it will delay things.  They could end up spending time breaking the door to gain access.  You can leave a decorative keyhole cover for appearance, but it would be better to replace the crystal knob with one with a privacy lock.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we can't really figure out resale value here.

Answer (score 5):

Privacy locksets (generally used for bathrooms and bedrooms) are designed to be *less* secure than a keyed lockset or deadbolt for a reason. In the event that access is needed from the outside (due to any number of circumstances important or mundane, see below) the privacy lockset can be opened from the outside with relative ease, usually with a small screwdriver or pointy tool.

Examples for easy access: child cannot manipulate locking feature to get out, someone accidentally locks the door behind them as they leave, someone has a medical emergency, someone slips in the shower/tub and is knocked unconscious, etc.

I do no not think it will lower the value of your home, but it is unusual and thus will prompt questioning.

Comment: +1 for warning about the safety aspect. In fact I would be much stronger and indicate that you should never install a deadbolt on a bathroom door. Kids and incapacitated people can die due to a careless installation like this.

Comment: `someone accidentally locks the door behind them as they leave`

a deadbolt cannot lock behind you

`Kids and incapacitated people can die`

The inside of the bathroom has a dial, so the person inside the bathroom could never get locked in. 

`someone has a medical emergency`

The key to the deadbolt could be kept in a closet or some other place close by that is never locked, In the event of an emergency, the door could be opened from the outside by retrieving the key.

Comment: Get a new lock set of the same type as the original. IMO buyers *do* care about aesthetics; having period hardware is a selling point.

Comment: @Jesse Adam, it is not just about **you** knowing where the key is, what if it is *you* that is having a medical emergency? I would suggest that the key be left in the lock just as is advised for dbl. cylinder deadbolts on entry/exit doors (it is commonly advised that the key remain in the lock of double-cylinder deadbolts on entry/exit doors while the home is occupied, to facilitate easy egress in the case of fire).

Comment: "a deadbolt cannot lock behind you", yes they can if they have the right (wrong) type of latch. "The inside of the bathroom has a dial, so the person inside the bathroom could never get locked in", yes they could especially *kids and incapacitated people*, they get panicky and confused particularly under stressful situations. Whatever, do what you want; I still say it is weird and if I saw it I would say so.